Can a planet without a satellite be suitable and how will this affect its climate and appearance?
I want to create a planet where there will be 2 suns (small races nearby) and without the moon, so that it is very dark at night. But because of this there are many problems with water and geography, and probably the atmosphere?

It's not clear what you're looking for here.  "Can a planet without a satellite be suitable..."  - suitable for what?  Evolution of native life?  Then the title is asking about the planet's appearance - we don't know enough about it to say - and then you appear to be asking about some problems with water, geography and atmosphere - again, we don't know what the problems are or how they relate to the absence of a satellite (assume you are talking about a moon-sized body).  Please edit into the title and question enough information to let us address a single problem.

The basic hydrological cycle is not reliant on the presence of a large moon, as such neither is most weather. The influence of the moon is notable in terms of the tide, approximately 2/3 of Earth's tides are due to lunar gravity, and in terms of stabilising the axis of Earth's rotational axis. Without a large moon there will still be a water cycle rain etc... but there will be no intertidal zone, which may, or may not, severely limit evolution on the world in question. More importantly without a large moon a planet may have issues with the stability of it's axial tilt, it has been estimated that Earth's obliquity would rise to 90° within a billion years without the stabilising influence of the moon.
